# How to set an index signature on a class that has multiple value types in typescript?

Tags: typescript

In typescript if I have

```
interface A {
    foo: number;
    bar: string;
    [state: string]: number
}
```

but this only allows the prop foo to be supported, not bar. How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? Why is `bar` not supported, and supported by what?

Comment: What if `state` takes the value `'bar'` - in that case the signature says the value should be a `number`, but it would actually be a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

To allow the value to be anything:

```
interface A {
    foo: number;
    bar: string;
    [state: string]: any
}
```

To allow number or string:

```
interface A {
    foo: number;
    bar: string;
    [state: string]: number | string
}
```

To allow number or specific strings:

```
interface A {
    foo: number;
    bar: string;
    [state: string]: number | "foo" | "bar"
}
```